# Android Compose - Request Focus

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Unable to gain focus on any compose component. It use to work in the project but after some gradle changes, only in some screens i can request focus. So i started a new project to test out the behavior in a clean environment. With this setup, onFocusChange gets the values "inactive" before requestFocus (which is correct) then changes to "deactivated", and after requestFocus, nothing. This is a new project with almost no code

```
@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
    Button(
        onClick = {},
        modifier = Modifier
            .focusRequester(focusRequester = focusRequester)
            .onFocusChanged {
                it
            }
            .wrapContentSize()
        ,
    ) {
        Text(text = "Hello $name!")
    }
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        this.coroutineContext.job.invokeOnCompletion {
            focusRequester.requestFocus()
        }
    }
}
```

And in my build.gradle, where compose_version = 1.1.1

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0'
}
```

Comment: What is your final goal?

Comment: Not sure where from is this line `this.coroutineContext.job.invokeOnCompletion`, the code will work the same with direct call `LaunchedEffect(Unit) { focusRequester.requestFocus() }`. From your question seems like you're expecting some second call of `requestFocus`, as the first one works fine, but I don't see any second call in your code

Comment: so i got closer to the issue but i havent found it in source code. if i use accompanist library 0.20.3 instead of "ui:ui", it works. but using the newer accompanist breaks it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You NEED to add the `focusable` modifier. It should come AFTER the `onFocusChanged` and `focusRequestor` Modifiers, and can also be replaced by `focusTarget` in some cases. See [focusRequestor](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/focus/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).focusRequester(androidx.compose.ui.focus.FocusRequester))

Comment: you dont need that modifier its enabled by default, and i tried that already

Comment: Are you using Material3 APIs?

Comment: Also, could you point where it is mentioned that the focusable modifier is enabled by default? I don't think I read that anywhere, though does seem to make sense.

Comment: im sorry you were right, it does work when focusable is at the bottom. i was testing my other app and it wasnt working there but works on the blank project. in the other app i have the focus modifiers on onGloballyPositioned, so im wondering if there was an update to one of the libraries that it stopped working there

Comment: You're sorry that I was right?

Comment: sorry for the doubt :P

Comment: Solving your problem was super-easy, barely an inconvenience.